# API Request works perfectly on Postman but returns empty body in response from Mulesoft API

Tags: request, mule, anypoint-studio, mule4

I'm doing the same request on Postman and on a Mule Flow.
If I use a simple request body (a JSON with 60 lines for example), it works fine on both.
But then, when I use a big request (it has 5545 lines), this problem occurs.

EDIT:

ok, just to make it clear since its all basicly dummy data and I need help. IF the request body has only this 5 items on the order array (the request is too long for this post, so i'm making it smaller for example purporses) it works fine:

```
{

"orders": [

    {

        "increment_id": "000001501",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },

    {

        "increment_id": "000001502",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },

    {

        "increment_id": "000001503",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },

    {

        "increment_id": "000001504",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },

    {

        "increment_id": "000001505",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },

]

}
```

BUT, if this same request contains like 8 or more items in the "orders" array, the respose body returns empty:

```
{

"orders": [

    {

        "increment_id": "000001501",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },

    {

        "increment_id": "000001502",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },

{

        "increment_id": "000001503",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },
{

        "increment_id": "000001504",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },
{

        "increment_id": "000001505",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },

{

        "increment_id": "000001506",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },

{

        "increment_id": "000001507",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },

{

        "increment_id": "000001508",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    },

{

        "increment_id": "000001509",

        "old_order_id": "",

        "total_qty_ordered": 1,

    }

]

}
```

The request headers differs as it follows:

Mulesoft request header:

```
POST /api/v1/SALES_ORDER HTTP/1.1
x-correlation-id: 1a0d03f0-626d-11eb-9b2e-b663a1179158
Host: HOST:PORT
User-Agent: AHC/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 165216
```

Postman request header:

```
POST /api/v1/SALES_ORDER HTTP/1.1
Host: HOST:PORT
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.10
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 165216
```

Again, I'm sending the SAME BODY request, but even tough the response is a 200 status code, the body on Mulesoft is returned empty (even the "Content-length" header is 0 only on Mulesoft)

Mulesoft response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2021 17:51:06 GMT
Server: Apache
Upgrade: h2
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5rNuv5ZX5ohn96xcd9YKahXSw414wxzZ7Y3PIRqw.loyaltyqaukpt; path=/b2becon
Set-Cookie: com.anm.octashop.country=IN; path=/
Set-Cookie: com.anm.octashop.lang=pt; path=/
country: IN
Content-Length: 0
Content-Language: pt-
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

Postman responde header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2021 17:51:06 GMT
Server: Apache
Upgrade: h2
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=xeqWEjuRcZ319zd8ZXtOnF0xN_-NEi-xygwGk05p.loyaltyqaukpt; path=/b2becon
Set-Cookie: com.anm.octashop.country=IN; path=/
Set-Cookie: com.anm.octashop.lang=pt; path=/
country: IN
Content-Length: 4372
Content-Language: pt-
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

EDIT (Versions):
Mule Server Runtime: 4.3.0

API Kit Module: 1.4

Anypoint MQ Connector - Mule 4: 3.1.2

HTTP Connector - Mule 4: 1.5.23

MUnit: 2.3.1

MUnit Tools: 2.3.1

Secure Configuration Property Extension - Mule 4: 1.2.3

Sockets Connector: 1.2.1

Comment: it sounds like MuleSoft is configured to not include the body in the response, can you verify this?

Comment: MulesSoft Is a company name. I guess you are making an HTTP request from a flow in Mule application that is deployed into a Mule Runtime. What is the version of Mule? If Mule 4.x.x, what is the version of the HTTP connector? Add the flow and HTTP  connector configuration. Where is the payload coming from? Is it complete in the request? Identical to the postman request?

Comment: @blurfus how can I verify that? I've got other 8 flows that also makes external API calls and they work fine (again, they all receive a small JSON request, whereas the problem with this one seems to be with the request body size)

Comment: @aled edited the question with the versions been used. I can guarantee it's the same request body used in Mule and Postman because, after transforming the payload, I've put a breakpoint on the HTTP Request, and copied that same request from Mule to Postman. Works fine on Postman, but I'm receiving an empty body response on Mule.

Comment: That's not the best way to troubleshoot this issue. Just in case there is something different being sent enable HTTP wire logging: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging
Note that there is a header that is different: `x-correlation-id: 1a0d03f0-626d-11eb-9b2e-b663a1179158`.
In any case, it is the server that is returning a different answer for apparently the same request (sans said header). Did you check from the server side?
Another way to troubleshoot is to capture the traffic, if it not HTTPS, with wireshark/tcpdump, to truly be sure of any difference.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your issue, the request through postman is working fine but in mules flow it is creating an issue than the issue is in our mule flow

try to debug your code and put debug points

1. at HTTP requestor of external API that you are hitting in mule flow
2. after HTTP requestor

check in the debugger that what the response is coming just after the HTTP requestor is empty or not.

Thanks

Comment: yes, it's returning an empty response for Mule, but only when there are 8 or more items in the "orders" array. I've edited with a request example if it was not clear. Again, any quantity works fine on Postman, but Mule I've got this 0 to 7 items limit. More than that it always return empty.

Comment: as I said did you check it in debug mode?